# AWS / Ubuntu Setup is automatically downgrading PHP somehow and breaking server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm having an extremely weird problem.

I'm running an AWS instance with Ubuntu and a few hours ago, my instance/Ubuntu **automatically** downgraded from PHP 7.4 to 7.2 completely breaking my site.

I had to manually upgrade back to PHP 7.4 to fix it. This is the second time it's happened in 2 days. At first, I thought it was a docker issue, so I removed all instances of docker, but it's happened once again.

The instance itself hasn't been restarted in 80 days.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Any suggestions?

[Logs when issue happened first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6yQ0.jpg)

Comment: That's a weird one!  You wouldn't happen to be running AWS Systems Manager to manage that instance, would you?  I'm wondering if there's some sort of AWS Config + Systems Manager config set up to keep packages at a specific version.

If that's not the issue, you could enable AWS Config to track changes to that instance, at least to get you more info about when it's happening, and hopefully see what is triggering it.  Also, you may want to check out CloudTrail to see if there may be any related events to that instance.

Comment: The logs say there is an automatic `apt upgrade` running every day on your server. Are you not installing PHP through `apt`? If not then you probably need to disable that automatic upgrade task.